# How to convert tensor to image in node.js and send it to client to download?

Tags: tensorflow.js, nodejs-stream

I have the following tensor in nodejs:

[image]

I then encode it to PNG like so:

```
const encodedTensor = await tf.node.encodePng(intTensor);
```

And pipe it to the frontend like this:

```
fs.writeFileSync("image.png", encodedTensor);
const readStream = fs.createReadStream('image.png');
readStream.pipe(res);
```

Finally, this is what shows up in my console:

[image]

What is this format? and how can I download the image on the client?
Or is there any other way of converting the tensor to images in nodejs and then downloading it on the client?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the ouptut in the console is a stringified/damaged version of uint8 array. It gets damaged while being sent from the server to client.

That's why instead of sending it as an int8 array I converted it to a buffer on the server, and then the buffer to a base64 string like so:

```
const encodedTensor = await tf.node.encodePng(tensor);

const data = Buffer.from(encodedTensor).toString("base64");
res.send(data);
```

After that I used this function to download the image on the client:

```
function downloadBase64File(contentType, base64Data, fileName) {
  const linkSource = `data:${contentType};base64,${base64Data}`;
  const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
  downloadLink.href = linkSource;
  downloadLink.download = fileName;
  downloadLink.click();
}

downloadBase64File("image/png", response.data, "image.png");
```

Hope it helps someone.